# WFS request with Openlayers; blank request

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, wfs

I'm having trouble to add a WFS layer over an OSM map. At first I thought that my data had a problem, and I thus decided to adapt one of [the example on the Openlayers website](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-reprojection.html). I have no error returned, but the layer is not appearing... Instead, I see in Firebug that there is a WFS request made to the server, but it is empty

```
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs
```

No GET request or arguments whatsoever. I can correctly make the request and I get a xml file as a result (in eg Firefox). I thought it was maybe because of the a proxy and I set one up (the one in Openlayers FAQ), but I get the same thing.

Here is the code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>


        var map, layer;
            var epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");
            var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

        function init(){
            OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
            var cent=new OpenLayers.LonLat(6.59,46.39).transform(epsg4326,epsg900913);

            var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Open Street Map");
            var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("States", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    version: "1.0.0",
                    srsName: "EPSG:4326", // this is the default
                    url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType: "states",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                }),
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("ESPG:4326")
            });

            map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{
                projection: epsg900913,
                layers:[osm,wfs],
                center: cent,
                zoom: 10
            });
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
            map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div style="width:500px; height:500px" id="map"></div>
    <div id="coordinates"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've lost several more hours of my life due to my mild dyslexia. The line

```
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("ESPG:4326")
```

should read `EPSG`...

The proxy is also mandatory. However, quick followup: Why is the request I see in firebug

```
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs
```

and not something like

```
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GET...
```

Comment: are you using POST instead of GET?

Comment: ah, yes, it is a POST request. Is there a way to do a GET instead, to see the difference and tinker with it?